# Grouping XML child nodes with XSLT for Adobe Indesign

Tags: xml, xslt

Trying to group by Category using XSLT but I am a graphic designer with very depressing programming skills.
The desired output should omit the node "Category"
Can anyone help me with this one? I really appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance.

**Input**

```
<Root>
  <row>
    <Cat>Cocktails</Cat>
    <Title>Virgin Berry Mojito</Title>
    <Description>Schweppes Russian Wild Berry, Beerenmix, Limette, Minze, Rohrzucker</Description>
    <Price>7,90</Price>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Cat>Cocktails</Cat>
    <Title>Sportsman</Title>
    <Description>Ananas, Orange, Zitrone, Grenadine</Description>
    <Price>7,90</Price>
  </row>
     <row>
    <Cat>Aperitifs</Cat>
    <Title>Lillet Wild Berry</Title>
    <Description>Lillet Blanc, Schweppes Russian Wild Berry</Description>
    <Price>7,90</Price>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Cat>Aperitifs</Cat>
    <Title>Aperol Spritz</Title>
    <Description>Prosecco, Aperol, Sodawasser</Description>
    <Price>7,90</Price>
    </row>
</Root>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<Root>
  <row>
    <Cat>Cocktails</Cat>
    <Title>Virgin Berry Mojito</Title>
    <Description>Schweppes Russian Wild Berry, Beerenmix, Limette, Minze, Rohrzucker</Description>
    <Price>7,90</Price>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Title>Sportsman</Title>
    <Description>Ananas, Orange, Zitrone, Grenadine</Description>
    <Price>7,90</Price>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Cat>Aperitifs</Cat>
    <Title>Lillet Wild Berry</Title>
    <Description>Lillet Blanc, Schweppes Russian Wild Berry</Description>
    <Price>7,90</Price>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Title>Aperol Spritz</Title>
    <Description>Prosecco, Aperol, Sodawasser</Description>
    <Price>7,90</Price>
  </row>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an an identity template that copies everything unchanged: in XSLT 3.0 that's

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

and in earlier versions it's

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then a rule that drops a Cat element if it's the same as its immediate predecessor:

```
<xsl:template match="Cat[.=../preceding-sibling::row[1]/Cat]"/>
```